# jquery function doesn't executed

Tags: jquery

i am using this jQuery function but when i run my application this function doesn't executes.

actually control goes to this func.but doesn't go inside this to execute code in it.

what is the reason??

this func.is used for check uncheck of radio.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
    var previousValue = $(this).attr('previousValue');
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if (previousValue == 'checked') {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).attr('previousValue', false);
    } else {
        $("input[name=" + name + "]:radio").attr('previousValue', false);
        $(this).attr('previousValue', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: i want to check uncheck radio input.

Comment: yes that I got, but what is `previousValue`

Comment: i got this func.i jst paste it.i think some .js file i have to include. previousValue means the presvious status of radio.

Comment: @user2243331 show your html .

Comment: <input type='radio' " + disable.toLowerCase() + );' name='AnswerOption' id='option" + (a + 1) + "' value='" + (a + 1) + "' />

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

and

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instated of .click()

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
    var previousValue = $(this).prop('previousValue');
    var name = $(this).prop('name');
    if (previousValue == 'checked') {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).prop('previousValue', false);
    } else {
        $("input[name=" + name + "]:radio").prop('previousValue', false);
        $(this).prop('previousValue', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @user2243331 what do you mean ?

Comment: The only JS file it depends on is jQuery.

Comment: it is not working.i mean control doesn't goes inside that function.

Comment: its dificult for me to paste complete code here.can u pls tell me all the posibility why this is not working????

Comment: @user2243331 paste only radio button code and html .Is your site live ?

Comment: i simply want to check n uncheck radio button. so i implemented onclick event.but issue is that when i click first time it returns true.but it should return false.when i use onmousedown event it returns false for first click.as expected.can u explain me why is it so. and also pls provide some solution for this.

Comment: @user2243331 i need you html.Post your html .

Comment: <input type='radio' " + disable.toLowerCase() + " onclick='handleRadioClick(" 
                        + this.id + ", event);' name='AnswerOption' id='option" + (a + 1) + "' value='" + (a + 1) + "' />

Comment: this is a function handleRadioClick(id,e)
  {
   if(!HCList[id].setObjDetail())
    { } 
    var targetElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
     optionState = targetElement.checked;
     if(optionState==true) 
     { targetElement.checked = false;}
     }

Comment: the optionState in the line optionState = targetElement.checked; returns true at first click